# perl Parallel::ForkManager - глобальные переменные

Tags: многопоточность, perl

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в ForkManager делится переменной между процессами.
Пример скрипта:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

our (@Print);
my $fileLog = 'test.txt';
$pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(5);

sub myFunc {
    my ($s) = @_;
    push(@Print, $s);
}

open(my $file, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $fileLog);
while (my $row = <$file>) {
         my $pid = $pm->start and next;
            myFunc($row);
         $pm->finish;
}
close $file;
$pm->wait_all_children; 


print @Print;
```

Comment: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch16_13.htm

Comment: @Mike, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использование разделяемой памяти поможет, да. Но оно же чревато проблемами. Например, при крахе скрипта, или просто остановке его под отладчиком, выделенная память зависает занятой. Что может привести в конечном итоге к неработоспособности системы в целом.

Варианты:

1. Использовать штатные средства модуля для передачи данных из потомков в процесс-родитель. Примеры см. в документации по модулю: [Parallel::ForkManager->EXAMPLES->Data structure retrieval](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager#Data-structure-retrieval).
2. Наладить обмен данными между родителем и потомками самостоятельно. Например, с помощью сокетов, пайпов, или как-то ещё.
3. Отказаться от форков в принципе. Распараллеливать процессы можно многими способами: Mojo::IOLoop, AnyEvent, Coro...

Пример как можно обойтись без разделяемой памяти, и с учётом ответа на [параллельный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545967):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use Socket;
use IO::Select;
use Fcntl;
use Data::Printer;
use constant CHILDREN => 3;

# здесь мы накапливаем строки в потомках:
my @child_lines;
# а сюда складываем результат в родителе:
my @parent_lines;
# каналы для записи в потомков:
my @writers;
my $current_writer = 0;

my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager( CHILDREN );

# эта процедура вызывается при завершении потомков:
$pm->run_on_finish(
  sub {
    my ($pid, $exit_code, $ident, $exit_signal, $core_dump, $dataref) = @_;
    push @parent_lines, @{$dataref};
  }
);

$SIG{'PIPE'} = 'IGNORE';

for( 1 .. CHILDREN ) {

  my ( $writer, $reader );

  # создаём анонимные сокеты для общения:
  socketpair( $reader, $writer, AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, PF_UNSPEC );   
  # в принципе эти сокеты можно использовать и
  # для получения результатов из потомков (даже ПРАВИЛЬНЕЙ
  # было бы использовать), но тут просто демка

  my $pid = $pm->start;
  if( $pid ) {

    close $reader;
    _set_opt( $writer );

    push @writers, $writer;
    next;
  }

  close $writer;
  _set_opt( $reader );

  # пока приходят строки - просто сохраняем их:
  while( my $line = <$reader> ) {
    chomp $line;
    push @child_lines, [ $$, $line ];
  }
  close $reader;

  # при завершении потомка вызывается run_on_finish со 
  # ссылкой на массив накопленных в потомке строк:
  $pm->finish(0, \@child_lines );
}

while( my $line = <STDIN> ) {

  chomp $line;
  next unless $line;

  # перебираем каналы потомков в цикле и пишем
  # в каждый из них входную строку:
  say {$writers[$current_writer]} $line;

  $current_writer++;
  $current_writer = 0 if $current_writer > $#writers;
}

close $_ for @writers;
$pm->wait_all_children;

# теперь в @parent_lines находятся все обработанные строки:
p @parent_lines;

sub _set_opt {
    my ( $sock ) = @_;
    $sock->autoflush(1);
    my $flags = fcntl( $sock, F_GETFL, 0 );
    fcntl( $sock, F_SETFL, $flags | O_NONBLOCK );
}
```

И насколько проще это можно сделать при помощи [Mojo::IOLoop](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/IOLoop):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Mojo::IOLoop;
use Data::Lock qw/dlock dunlock/;
use Data::Printer;
use constant WORKERS => 3;

my @result;
my $worker;
my $active_workers = 0;

$worker = sub 
{
    while( 1 ) 
    {
      my $line = <STDIN>;
      unless ($line) {
        return $active_workers ? undef : Mojo::IOLoop->stop();
      }

      chomp $line;
      if( $line ) 
      {
        $active_workers++;
        # что-то делаем и сохраняем:
        dlock @result;
        push @result, $line;
        dunlock @result;
        $active_workers--;
      }
    }
};

$worker->() for 1 .. WORKERS;
Mojo::IOLoop->start();

p @result;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Модифицировал свой скрипт под ваш вариант (Mojo::IOLoop) и его скорость работы увеличилась в 40 раз по сравнению с вариантом на форках.

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал способ №2