# perl Parallel::ForkManager - дублирует процессы

Tags: многопоточность, perl

Использую `Parallel::ForkManager` для многопоточности на perl.
Сам скрипт в принципе простой, открывается файл и оттуда считываются данные в массив, после циклом `while` открывается массив и с помощью `ForkManager` данные передаются в функцию для обработки. Но вот проблема в том, что если на входе должно быть 15 вызовов функции, то на выходе их может быть 15+n (иногда на 1 или на 10 больше раз вызывается), т.е., в цикле какой-то из вызовов дублируется.

Можно ли это как то проверить, что бы не дублировались данные? На выходе данные немного отличаются из одинаковых функций (там считается время и данные не совпадают на 1 секунду) из-за чего этот дубль нельзя выкинуть из массива.

**Сам скрипт:**

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use Text::ParseWords;
use IPC::Shareable;

my @wPrint = 0;
my $handle = tie @wPrint, 'IPC::Shareable', { destroy => 'Yes' };

my $fileLog = 'test.txt';

$pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(5);

sub myFunc {
    my ($s) = @_;
      my @arr = quotewords(":", 0, $s);
$handle->shlock();
    push(@wPrint, $arr[0].":".$arr[1].":".$arr[2].":".$arr[3].":".$arr[4].":\n");
$handle->shunlock();    
}

open(my $file, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $fileLog);
while (my $row = <$file>) {
         my $pid = $pm->start and next;
            myFunc($row);
         $pm->finish;
}
close $file;
$pm->wait_all_children; 


print @wPrint;
IPC::Shareable->clean_up_all;
```

Данные в файле в таком виде:

```
10.0.0.1:Имя 1:0:0:0:
10.0.0.2:Имя 2:0:0:0:
10.0.0.3:Имя 3:0:0:0:
```

Comment: Обратите внимание, в примере что я вам дал с IPC::Shareable при tie получается некий $handle и перед каждым использованием переменной в процессах берется блокировка для этого ресурса и после работы с переменной освобождается. Без блокировок содержимое переменной непредсказуемо. Хотя может тут у вас дело и не в этом, но блокировки разделяемой памяти в многопоточной среде строго обязательны

Comment: @Mike Я пробовал выводить результат работы функции "myFunc" через обычный print (т.е. не использовалась не какая переменная для хранения данных) и результат тот же. То есть идут дубликаты изначально. По поводу буфера сейчас допишу.

Comment: Если запускать функцию без ForkManager, то не каких дубликатов нет, т.е. все передается построчно как записано в файле без двойных вызовов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу понять почему именно это происходит, но при работе fork основной цикл чтения файла `$file` иногда повторяет чтение одних и тех же данных. Подозреваю, что связано с особенностями работы буферизирования и файловых дескрипторов в perl. Второй процесс скорее всего получает копию этих дескрипторов и с ними там что то происходит. Лечится предварительным чтением всего входного файла в массив и работа цикла уже по данным из массива:

```
open(my $file, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $fileLog);
my @rows=do{local $/; split(/\n/,<$file>)};
close $file;
foreach my $row (@rows) {
         my $pid = $pm->start and next;
            myFunc($row);
         $pm->finish;
}
```

Comment: спасибо! Действительно это вылечило проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню. Во-первых, считать файл в массив можно проще :)

```
my @rows = <$file>;
```

Во-вторых, негуманно засасывать весь файл в память. Куда правильней читать его через `STDIN`, заодно это и решит проблему со скачками файловых указателей:

```
while( my $row = <STDIN> ) {
    chomp $row;
    next unless $row;
    $pm->start and next;
```

Ну и самое главное. Подход это неверен в принципе. Потому как для небольших файлов параллелить обработку нет вообще никакого смысла. А для больших - дерготня форк на каждую строку вряд ли повысит эффективность обработки. Я бы сразу нафоркал какое-то количество потомков заранее, а данные им передавал через какой-нибудь менеджер очереди из родительского процесса.